# How to redirect to different component after successful login from Google API

Tags: jquery, html, firebase, angular2-routing

I am creating an application in angular2 with firebase . I have configured the firebase into my application .I have given a login button which is calling GoogleLogin method .Under that i have used  signinpop method. I want to redirect to a different component after successful login ,could not find any suitable online help ,moreover i have used some css and jquery in my index.html page for scrolling effect (ui.component.html) .The problem is when i am routing to another page (routes ) and pressing back browser back button the scrolling effect does not work.

Image: [Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDL4k.png)

This is my ui.component.html

```
<section  class="projects">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Want to see Projects &mdash; Simple as 1,2,3</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
 <div class="col span_1_of_2 steps_box">
     <img src="../assets/image/projectimage.png" class="mobile_screen js--wp-2">
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_2 steps_box">
    <div class="work_step clearfix">
        <div>1</div>
        <p>We have quite a good list of projects in jquery and JavaScript,want to see the projects-keep reading</p>
    </div>
     <div class="work_step clearfix">
        <div>2</div>
        <p> It's free -yes you heard correct, Just Sign In with your Gmail Account </p>
    </div>
     <div class="work_step clearfix">
        <div>3</div>
        <p>Access the pandora of projects .It will surely help you in learning JavaScript and jquery</p>
    </div>

    <a class="btn btn-full" href="#" (click)="loginWithGoogle()" >Login</a>

 </div>

    </div>


</section>

<br>
<br>
```

This is my ui.component.ts class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ui',
  templateUrl: './ui.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ui.component.css']
})
export class UiComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public afAuth:AngularFireAuth,db:AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

loginWithGoogle()
{
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())



}

}
```

Javascript library

```
  $(document).ready(function()
    {


    /* for sticky navigation ---*/

    $('.js--section-features').waypoint(function(direction){

        if(direction=="down")
        {
    $('nav').addClass('sticky');

        }
        else
        {
          $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
        }
    },
    {offset:'60px;'}
    );



    /* for scroll buttons */

    $('.js--scroll-to-Technology').click(function()
    {

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.js--section-features').offset().top},1000)
    })

    $('.js--scroll-to-start').click(function()
    {

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.js--scroll-section-form').offset().top},1000)
    })





    /* for scroll links */


    $('.hello').click(function(){

        $('html ,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.aboutme').offset().top},1000)
    })

    $('.project').click(function(){

        $('html ,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.projects').offset().top},1000)
    })




      /*Animations on scroll----*/

      $('.js--wp-1').waypoint(function(direction)
      {

          $('.js--wp-1').addClass('animated fadeIn');
      },

     { offset:'50%'});

     $('.js--wp-2').waypoint(function(direction)
      {

          $('.js--wp-2').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
      },

     { offset:'50%'});

      $('.js--wp-3').waypoint(function(direction)
      {

          $('.js--wp-3').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
      },

     { offset:'50%'});


    });
```